# How to configure the address to fetch for repositories in gitlab runners?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I see that my runner is trying to clone the repository from `localhost:8081`.

The problem is that my repository is on the gitlab server which is not `localhost:8081`.

How do I tell my gitlab to tell to the runner that he has another address (like `10.29.39.29:43823`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitLab should send the repo URL to the Runner, so if GitLab is sending `localhost:8081` while it's really on `10.29.39.29:43823` then the GitLab instance is what's misconfigured, not the Runner.

[According to the Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#configuring-the-external-url-for-gitlab) you can set the external URL by adding/editing `etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` with `external_url "http://gitlab.example.com"`, in your case `external_url 10.29.39.29:43823`. After that, run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` and the Runner should work.

If you're not using Omnibus (and you definitely should be, since this kind of thing is a decent bit more complicated), this won't work.

Assuming that doesn't work, are you hosting it yourself? What version of GitLab and GitLab Runner are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You may also change the runner's config.toml:

```
[[runners]]
  clone_url = "10.29.39.29:43823"
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#how-clone_url-works

Answer (score 0):

First, double-check "[Using Docker Images](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html)"

> Docker, when used with GitLab CI, runs each build in a separate and isolated container using the predefined image that is set up in [`.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html).
>
> To use GitLab Runner with docker you need to register a new runner to use the docker executor:

```
gitlab-ci-multi-runner register
```

You can also check this docker image: [`sameersbn/docker-gitlab-ci-multi-runner`](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab-ci-multi-runner): Use this image to build your CI runner images.
See [issue 4](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/4#issuecomment-143376392) as an example (where `CI_SERVER_URL` is clearly set)

Comment: Interesting read also: https://snorre.io/setting-up-gitlab-ci-runner-docker-image-builder/

Comment: Ci_server_url is set otherwise the runner won't start its just the repository URL that is wrong

Comment: @miniHouse OK. what version are you using? (od the OS, GitLab, GitLab runner, docker, ...)

Comment: the docker image you mentioned

Comment: @miniHouse I mean what version are you using (of everthing: OS, gitlab, docker, and so on): what  are you using beside the image I mentioned?